# How to store unicode to mysql with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode

I have a text field in a Django (1.4) model, I am trying to save a record to MySQL using MySQLdb.

MySQL is using UTF-8 charset.

I am trying to store a Unicode string:

```
u"\u2019"
```

I expected to be able to just use Unicode in Django to be automatically converted to UTF-8 for storage.

However I get the error:

```
*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position *: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now I noticed that I can fix the error if I manually encode the string to UTF-8 before saving.

```
mystring.encode("utf-8")
```

Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**: example code

here is the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    textfield = models.TextField()

> mystring = u'\u2019'
> print mystring
’
> MyModel(mystring).save()
*** UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
> MyModel(mystring.encode("utf-8")).save() #this instead works
```

Comment: What's the database charset?

Comment: He said _MySQL is using UTF-8 charset_. You're right, Django should do this for you, can you provide some context where you're writing the string to the db?

Comment: Please post the code that causes the problem.

Comment: the database charset is UTF-8 as well, I do not have a standalone example code, I'll prepare it tomorrow.

Comment: That code worked for me out of the box :( Have you modified anything about encodings in your settings.py?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. Maybe make sure you are really using MySQL in your settings, then double check your MySQL database charset.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your `my.ini` config file for MySql says `utf8` as default charset encoding?

Comment: I'll check again, however, if it works when I explicitly encode in `utf8`, doesn't that mean that MySQL is correctly configured?

Comment: By the way, on the same setup, I switched from `MySQL` to `sqlite` and that works as well.

Comment: in `my.cnf` I have: `collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci character_set_server=utf8`, and from `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;` I see that the column's collation is correctly: `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: `collation` and `charset` are related but different things. This should work if MySql is configured properly. In my `my.ini` those settings are called `default_character_set=utf8`.

Comment: It must be a misconfiguration on my server. I found no solution to this, I'll just keep the manual encoding.